# Approximation of $ _2F_1((b-1)a,b;ba;x) $

Tags: special-functions, approximation-theory, hypergeometric-functions

Is there any (simple) approximation of this Hypergeometric function: $ _2F_1((b-1)a,b;ba;x) $, where $0<x<1$ and $b>a>1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Other than the Maclaurin polynomials?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, if possible.. Note that I can accept the following assumption: $x\ll1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are Pade approximations. See [these slides by Matala-aho.](http://cc.oulu.fi/~tma/TOKYOSLIDES.pdf) I believe the results in the classical case you are asking about are due to Grisha Chudnovsky (1979, cited in the slides).